# $e in php exceptions

Tags: php, exception

I'm new to PHP and was browsing php.net, where I came across this piece of code:

```
<?php
function inverse($x) {
    if (!$x) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    return 1/$x;
}

try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

// Continue execution
echo "Hello World\n";
?>
```

What exactly is `$e`? Can it be renamed? What does it do? Why do we need it?

Comment: just read the documentation

Comment: @Leggendario I googled it and didn't find anything related...

Comment: also you'd benefit from reading up on what Exceptions are and how try-catch works. Basically $e is an instance of said Exception, in OOP exceptions are just objects (and yes, you can rename it)

Comment: `$e` is simply the variable to hold the `Exception` Object, yes it can be renamed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply a variable, you can call it whatever you want. Basically the variable points to the Exception-object, and it's conventionally called $e as "e" is short for **E**xception.

Also, when using Exceptions, it's a good idea to create your own Exception-classes by just creating a new class that extends Exception. For example:

```
<?php

class AuthException extends Exception {}

class SuspendedException extends Exception {}
```

In this case, you can `throw new AuthException()` should a user fail to authenticate. On the other hand, if a user manages to login but is suspended from your page, you can `throw new SuspendedException()`.

This way you can extend your try-catch-blocks to catch different exceptions and handle them differently.

```
<?php

try {
    //logging your user in
} catch (AuthException $ae) {
    //handle an unauthorized user
} catch (SuspendedException $se) {
    //handle a suspended user
}
```

Notice how I'm using `$ae` and `$se` rather than a plain `$e` - as I said earlier, those are only variables and can be named whatever you like. Just try to stay consistent with your code.

Comment: what if i have several exceptions?

Comment: You don't. You can only throw and catch one at a time.

Comment: The try-block fails on the first exception thrown, so there can't be multiple exception.

Comment: @ufosecret Then you should have a unique variable for each Exception. However the `catch (Exception $e)` catches all Exceptions, so it would only catch the first one being thrown.

Comment: you can have several exceptions however you can only catch one at a time. so $e is just enough.

Answer (score 2):

`$e` is a variable that holds an `Exception` object, so yes you can rename it. What it does is that if there is some exception in your try-block then the catch-block runs, so there you can fetch the exception, maybe log it, try something else or print an useful error to the user.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 0):

It can be renamed to any legal PHP variable name, and has message and related info to the exception that happened. Use `var_dump()` to see information.